# Add multiple data in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, servicenow

Guys this is a service now code but I have java script doubt in this,I am trying to display a data in a `marquee`

```
<div>
<marquee><b ng-repeat='val in data.arr'><label>{{val.display_field}}</label></b></marquee>
</div>
```

getting array from server side.

```
(function() {
    data.arr = [];
    var record={};
    var display_value='';
    var announce=new GlideRecord('announcement');
    announce.addQuery('active=true');
    announce.query();
    while(announce.next()){
        display_value = announce.getValue('name') ;
        record.display_field=display_value; 
    }
    data.arr.push(record);

})();
```

I will be getting more then one value in `announce.getValue('name')` like `test,test1,test2..` .I want to store these values as individual objects in an array,

```
[
    {
    display_field:test
    },
    {
    display_field:test1
    }
]
```

my bad ,marquee displays only the final value i.e `test2`.object overriding the previous values. how can I get all values in an array?

Comment: FYI: `marquee` is obsolete HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2?p=preview). Also please check the below code for dynamic announcement to be added by button click.

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.data = {
    arr: [{
      display_field: 'test'
    },{
      display_field: 'test1'
    }]
  };
  $scope.getMoreAnnouncment = function(){
    var newAnnoucement = {
      display_field: 'test' + ($scope.data.arr.length + 1)
    }
    $scope.data.arr.push(newAnnoucement);
  }
```

**Template:**

```
   <marquee>
      <div>
         <b ng-repeat='val in data.arr'>
           <label>{{val.display_field}}</label>
         </b>
      </div>
   </marquee>
   <button ng-click="getMoreAnnouncment()">Add one More</button>
```

Comment: `test,test1,test2` is just an example, so we cant add `+1` with length.How will you add `india,america`..?

Comment: Your existing function **announce.getValue('name')**  should take care of returning whatever data to be binded into your array. +1 is just for the example purpose not for the real-time implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution!!

We have to clear `record` object and `display_value` each and every time,then only a new object will be created.

(function() {
    data.arr = [];

```
var announce=new GlideRecord('announcement');
announce.addQuery('active=true');
announce.query();
while(announce.next()){
    var record={};
    var display_value='';
    display_value = announce.getValue('name') ;
    record.display_field=display_value; 
}
data.arr.push(record);
```

})();